# É um bug no CakePHP - Ordenar Aliases?

Tags: cakephp, order-by

Estou tentando ordenar uma query por relevância com o cakephp usando paginator, mas simplesmente ele ignora o alias, já pesquisei no manual mas até o momento não encontrei a solução, a query funciona perfeitamente, quando dou um debug gera a query abaixo, mas o order by não aparece veja:

```
    SELECT *, MATCH (`titulo`,`conteudo`) AGAINST ('e-mail marketing' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance, MATCH (`titulo`) AGAINST ('e-mail marketing' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS title_relevance FROM `db_forum`.`ra_forum` AS `Forum` WHERE MATCH (titulo,conteudo) AGAINST ('e-mail marketing' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10
```

Segue o código:

```
$this->paginate = array(

                'fields'     => array('*', "MATCH (`titulo`,`conteudo`) AGAINST ('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance,  MATCH (`titulo`) AGAINST ('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS title_relevance"),
                'conditions' =>  "MATCH (`titulo`,`conteudo`) AGAINST ('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE)",
                'order'      => array( 'relevance' => 'desc', 'title_relevance' => 'desc'),
                'limit'      => 10
        );
```

Algum macete para que isso funcione?

Edit:

Fica dica para quem precisar, eu estava colocando como parâmetros, o correto é:

```
'order'      => 'relevance desc, title_relevance desc',
```

Comment: Posso estar errado, mas acho que o 'order' só aceita um parametro. Você está tentando order usando duas coisas

Comment: Achei o erro, não é necessário passar por array é direto!

Comment: Na verdade, não está correto, você precisa referenciar o model, no início do array, ou em cada campo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto é aliar o model ao campo.

```
array(
    'conditions' => array('Model.field' => $thisValue), //array of conditions
    'recursive' => 1, //int
    //array com os campos
    'fields' => array('Model.field1', 'DISTINCT Model.field2'),
    //string(1 campo) ou array(mais de 1 campo)
    'order' => array('Model.created', 'Model.field3 DESC'),
    'group' => array('Model.field'), //fields to GROUP BY
    'limit' => n, //int
    'page' => n, //int
    'offset' => n, //int
    'callbacks' => true //ou false, 'before', 'after'
);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Esta regra também se aplica ao `PaginatorComponent`

Pode usar esta resposta:
[Pagination mostra sempre 20 imagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17288/pagination-mostra-sempre-20-imagens)