# Pagination mostra sempre 20 imagens

Tags: cakephp, paginação

Estou a fazer uma galeria que utiliza a Pagination do CakePHP. O problema é que apenas quero mostrar 15 imagens por página, mas independentemente do valor que eu coloque em `public $paginate`, no limite, são sempre mostradas 20 imagens. Com a linha `$this->Paginator->settings =$this->paginate;` descomentada isto funciona, mas faz com que as rotas que contêm os números de página não funcionem correctamente. O DebugKit também mostra que o array `Soptions` está vazio. Porque é que isto acontece? Existe alguma forma de fazer com que isto funcione com esta linha comentada?
Estou a utilizar o Cake 2.4.4.

**Controller**

```
public $components = array('Paginator');
public $paginate = array('maxLimit' => 15, 'order' => array('modified' => 'desc'), 'contain' => array('GalleryImage', 'GalleryVideo'));

public function displayImages(){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Galeria de Fotografias');
        $this->layout = 'default';
        $this->loadModel('GalleryImage');

        //$this->Paginator->settings =$this->paginate;
        $gallery_images=$this->Paginator->paginate('GalleryImage');


        //$gallery_images = $this->GalleryImage->find('all');
        $this->set('gallery_images', $gallery_images);

    //$image_display = $gallery_image['path']
        debug($paginate);
  }
```

**View**

```
<style>
h3{

  text-align: left;
}
</style>
<h3>Galeria</h3>
<br>
 <table width="90%">
<tr>
    <?php
        $i=0;
        foreach( $gallery_images as $gallery_image ):?>
    <td align="center" class="thumbnail" style="display:inline-block;">
    <?php
        $src =$this->webroot. 'img/Gallery/' .$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['name'];
        echo "<a href=\"".$src. "\" rel=\"lightbox\">".$this->Timthumb->image('/img/Gallery/' . $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['name'] , array('width' => 267, 'height' => 189))."  </a>";
    ?>
    </td>
    <?php $i++;
        if($i==3){
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            $i=0;   
        }
    ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tr>

</table>
<div class="pagesDiv">
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><?php echo $this->Paginator->first(__('Primeira', true), array());?></li>
  <li><?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''  ,'currentTag' =>'span' ,'class' => 'numbers', 'first' => false, 'last' => false));?></li>
  <li><?php echo $this->Paginator->last(__('Última', true), array('class' => 'disabled'));?></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Já tentou usar só limit ao invés de maxLimit?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Era o que eu estava utilizando antes do maxLimit, e também não funciona.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Editei a minha pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isto:

```
public $paginate = array(
    'maxLimit' => 10,  //Registros por página
    'limit' => 100  //Registros por consulta
    'paramType' => 'querystring' //Esta linha analisa o parâmetro fornecido pelo link.
);
$this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
$resultado = $this->Paginator->paginate('Model');
```

O código acima resultaria em 10 páginas, com 100 resultados ao total.

Ou Assim:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'SeuModel' => array(
                'limit' => 20,
                'maxLimit' => 100,
                'order' => array('SeuModel.campo' => 'ASC') // Por exemplo
        ),
        'OutroModel' => array( ... )
);
```

Comment: Não funciona, era o que tinha antes do código actual.

Comment: O 'limit' é de versões anteriores

Comment: @MarceloAymone Editei a minha pergunta.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Mas na documentação apenas fala do `limit`.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo A documentação é da versão 2.x, se estiver usando a 2.4 ela é aplicável sim.

Comment: @Jim, você setou o `paginator` no arrays dos `helpers`?
Para a paginação funcionar corretamente, você precisa definir o helper, ele auxilia na geração dos links.

Comment: @MarceloAymone Ao que parece até estava em duplicado, mas depois de corrigir o problema continua na mesma.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta novamente.

Comment: @MarceloAymone Continua igual, a linha `$this->Paginator->settings =$this->paginate;`, é obrigatória para o Paginator utilizar os parâmetros em `public $paginate`?

Comment: Quando você define `$this->paginate` ela é só uma variável aonde você armazena as configurações do `PaginatorComponent`, se você não definir nada, ele vai usar a configuração `default`, por isso que está funcionando quando você desabilita.
Mas o nome tanto faz, pode definir até `$this->blaublau` que não importa, ou seja não é obrigatória, mas vai funcionar somente em modo `default`.

Comment: @MarceloAymone Sim mas `$this->Paginator->settings` é que vai fazer com que o Paginator utilize essas configurações não é?

Comment: Isso, se você definir diretamente também funcionaria.
Ex: `$this->Paginator->settings['limit'] = 10;`

Que é igual a:

`$this->paginate = array('limit' => 10);` e depois:
`$this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;`

Acho que a documentação incentiva a usar outro array para separar o array de configuração do array de chamada do componente.

Comment: Tente atribuir diretamente e depois manda debugar para ver o que ocorre... talvez o que esteja ocasionando o problema seja o `ContainebleBehavior`... É meio problemático com o `Paginator`.

Dá uma olhada aqui:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#using-containable-with-pagination

Comment: @MarceloAymone Utilizei o código `$this->Paginator->settings['limit'] = 15;` e parece estar a funcionar correctamente. Qual é o problema então?

Comment: Funcionou? Provavelmente a declaração do array `$paginate`.

Comment: @MarceloAymone Tentando modificar as opções da ordem da listagem, fico com as rotas das páginas todas desconfiguradas de novo. Existe alguma forma de resolver o problema sem que isso aconteça?

Comment: Atualizada a resposta.

Comment: @MarceloAymone Muito obrigado pelo seu apoio!